# Do dynamic arrays support a non-zero lower bound (for VarArrayCreate compatibility)?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, dynamic-arrays, variant

I'm going maintain and port to Delphi XE2 a bunch of very old Delphi code that is full of [VarArrayCreate](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.Variants.VarArrayCreate) constructs to fake dynamic arrays having a lower bound that is not zero.

Drawbacks of using [Variant](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Variant_Types) types are:

- quite a bit slower than native arrays (the code does a lot of complex financial calculations, so speed is important)
- not type safe (especially when by accident a wrong `var...` constant is used, and the Variant system starts to do unwanted conversions or rounding)

Both could become moot if I could use [dynamic arrays](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Structured_Types#Dynamic_Arrays).

Good thing about variant arrays is that they can have non-zero lower bounds.

What I recollect is that dynamic arrays used to always start at a lower bound of zero.

Is this still true? In other words: *Is it possible to have dynamic arrays start at a different bound than zero*?

As an illustration a before/after example for a specific case (single dimensional, but the code is full of multi-dimensional arrays, and besides [varDouble](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/System_varDouble.html), the code also uses various other `varXXX` data types that [TVarData](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.TVarData) allows to use):

```
function CalculateVector(aSV: TStrings): Variant;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  Result := VarArrayCreate([1,aSV.Count-1],varDouble);
  for I := 1 to aSV.Count-1 do
    Result[I] := CalculateItem(aSV, I);
end;
```

The `CalculateItem` function returns `Double`. Bounds are from `1` to `aSV.Count-1`.

Current replacement is like this, trading the space zeroth element of Result for improved compile time checking:

```
type
  TVector = array of Double;
function CalculateVector(aSV: TStrings): TVector;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(Result, aSV.Count); // lower bound is zero, we start at 1 so we ignore the zeroth element
  for I := 1 to aSV.Count-1 do
    Result[I] := CalculateItem(aSV, I);
end;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dynamic arrays always have a lower bound of `0`. So, `low(A)` equals `0` for all dynamic arrays. This is even true for empty dynamic arrays, i.e. `nil`.

From the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Structured_Types#Dynamic_Arrays):

> Dynamic arrays are always integer-indexed, always starting from 0.

Comment: Thanks, just making sure I hadn't missed a very obvious thing over the last 1.5 decade (:

Comment: I'm sure this will never change.

Comment: @David a while ago i was similarly sure that strings would always be 1-based :-D

Comment: @Arioch Hmm. That was always an anomoly.

Comment: @David depends on POV. To me that buffer[20] is out of bounds of buffer[20] is more of anomaly on it's own terms :-)
Since i now have to work with Excel COM which also enumerates every dynamic sequence from 1, the 0-based structures seem confusing to me :-)

Answer (score 2):

Having answered your direct question already, I also offer you the beginnings of a generic class that you can use in your porting.

```
type
  TSpecifiedBoundsArray<T> = class
  private
    FValues: TArray<T>;
    FLow: Integer;
    function GetHigh: Integer;
    procedure SetHigh(Value: Integer);
    function GetLength: Integer;
    procedure SetLength(Value: Integer);
    function GetItem(Index: Integer): T;
    procedure SetItem(Index: Integer; const Value: T);
  public
    property Low: Integer read FLow write FLow;
    property High: Integer read GetHigh write SetHigh;
    property Length: Integer read GetLength write SetLength;
    property Items[Index: Integer]: T read GetItem write SetItem; default;
  end;

{ TSpecifiedBoundsArray<T> }

function TSpecifiedBoundsArray<T>.GetHigh: Integer;
begin
  Result := FLow+System.High(FValues);
end;

procedure TSpecifiedBoundsArray<T>.SetHigh(Value: Integer);
begin
  SetLength(FValues, 1+Value-FLow);
end;

function TSpecifiedBoundsArray<T>.GetLength: Integer;
begin
  Result := System.Length(FValues);
end;

procedure TSpecifiedBoundsArray<T>.SetLength(Value: Integer);
begin
  System.SetLength(FValues, Value);
end;

function TSpecifiedBoundsArray<T>.GetItem(Index: Integer): T;
begin
  Result := FValues[Index-FLow];
end;

function TSpecifiedBoundsArray<T>.SetItem(Index: Integer; const Value: T);
begin
  FValues[Index-FLow] := Value;
end;
```

I think it's pretty obvious how this works. I contemplated using a `record` but I consider that to be unworkable. That's down to the mix between value type semantics for `FLow` and reference type semantics for `FValues`. So, I think a class is best here.

It also behaves rather weirdly when you modify `Low`.

No doubt you'd want to extend this. You'd add a `SetBounds`, a copy to, a copy from and so on. But I think you may find it useful. It certainly shows how you can make an object that looks very much like an array with non-zero lower bound.

Comment: At this specific client, I couldn't get on-line yesterday, so I wrote something similar yesterday morning (the class derives from `TInterfacedObject` so you can have similar automagic lifetime management as the `Variant`, and I also included bounds checking). When I have completed it, I will make it public though.

Comment: Yeah, all of those ideas sound very sensible. In particular using a reference counted interface will make the code that uses this object much cleaner to read and write.